# Java Eclipse Debug Terminating issue

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Ive been debugging a project in eclipse. I inserted a breakpoint on a while statement. All was working fine, I was monitoring the variable increments. I tried to change the test class, but forgot I was still running the program, a message popped up and asked a question (I can't remember the exact phrasing) and I clicked terminate. But now when I run the debugger, it runs through the program and gives me the following

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>
```

But it doesn't allow me to step through the program. I tried "skip all breakpoints" but that isn't the answer.. It has something to do with the pop up message I'm pretty sure.

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: Have tried restarting Eclipse? Replace your breakpoint, press the little bug to debug. Does that help? Clean project might help in those mysterious Eclipse cases as well.

Comment: I restarted eclipse, switched from debug to java and back again, deleted and replaced the breakpoint.. I even restarted the PC! still nothing

Comment: Did you code `System.exit(0);` somewhere in your test perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the debugger skips all breakpoints.

- Hit the search button in the top right corner
- Type skip all breakpoints
- Click the result.
- Debugger shall be working from now on.

I had the same issue earlier, I have found the answer on youtube :)